# Array to Array arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays

I have 24bit data in 3 array `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]` and need to calculate for multiply and divide by some constant and result still in 3 array.

For example,  `data = 999900h`  store in `a[0] = 99`, `a[1] = 99`, `a[2] = 00`

```
[(999900h/64)*15000]/157286 << **process???**
```

result will be `3A97h` store in `b[0] = 00`, `b[1] =3A`, `b[2] = 97`

My question is

1.) How to write code for fast calculate in the process, pointer in fast? how to use pointer in the process?

2.) It possible no use conversion process like array to integer and integer to array?

Comment: Wait, so you need to combine each element from each array into one integer, then what? Where does the divisor, multiplier or, well, the rest of it come from?

Comment: raw data is fix point Q24 and store in char array, So I have to convert to realize data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use unions in this case:

```
#inlude<stdint.h>

union array_int {
  char a[4];
  uint32_t num;
} data = {.a = {00, 99, 99, 00}};

printf("%d", data.num);
```

Please take endianess into account. use `htonl` if you put in your bytes most significant - to least significant, but are on a little endian system. If you don't want to mess around with endianess then I suggest you use one of the suggested algebraic suggestions.

Comment: This way I that expect. no convert array to interger. Thank very much

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest "solution":

```
 uint32_t data = 0x00999900;

 unsigned char const * a = (unsigned char const *)&data;
```

Now you have `a[0]`, ..., `a[3]`. The order depends on the endianness of your system.

---

The endianness-independent solution works algebraically:

```
uint32_t data = 0x3A97;

unsigned char b[sizeof data] = {  data >> 24  & 0xFF,       // b[0]
                                 (data >> 16) & 0xFF,       // b[1]
                                 (data >>  8) & 0xFF,       // b[2]
                                  data        & 0xFF        // b[3]
                               };
```

---

You can also reconstitute a value from your array. Here's the endianness-dependent way:

```
uint32_t data;
unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *)&data;
p[0] = 0x00;
p[0] = 0x99;
p[0] = 0x99;
p[0] = 0x00;

// now "data" is 0x00999900
```

And here's the algebraic way:

```
uint32_t data = a[0] * 256 * 256 * 256 + a[1] * 256 * 256 + a[2] * 256 + a[3];
```

Comment: But my raw data is a[0]=0x99 a[1]=0x99 a[2]=0x00

So I have to convert to uint32_t first right? If I not to convert It have other way to do that?